# jQuery easyTooltip Not Load With Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, tooltip

I use easyTooltip: http://pastebin.com/UjaDyE27

And it works fine. The HTML looks like this:

```
<ELEMENT class="tip">Something</ELEMENT>
<div class="tipContent">ToolTip Content</div>
```

This is works fine, but when I load the html with ajax - it doesn't works!
What is the problem?

Thanks, and sorry for my English

Comment: What could be the problem to set plugin on non existent element?!...

Comment: @A.Wolff I wrote it for example/ it could be `<div>`,`<span`> or anything else

Answer (score 2):

can you please this method after loading ajax content

```
         $(".tip").each(function() {
                $(this).easyTooltip({
                        content: $(this).next('.tipContent').html()
                });
         });
```

Comment: One more thing: I want that `onclick` (anywhere) the tooltip will disappear. How can I do that?

Comment: $('body').click(function() {
  $(".tip").each(function() {
                $(this).easyTooltip({
                        content: $(this).next('.tipContent').html()
                });
         });
});

Comment: Where do I put it? By the way: now I see that your solution isn't perfectly good, because if there are multiple divs with class `.tip`, when I hover them - I get two `.tipContent` div. (duplicated...)